# Cannot run a r package in python

Tags: r, python-3.x

I want to use the R package 'grpreg'. However, I do not want to run it in R. Instead, I want to run the package under python. I have searched that I need to install the package rpy2, which allows me to run an R package under python. After installing rpy2, I enter

```
> `from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr`
> `base=importr('grpreg')`
```

Unfortunately, I obtain the error messages:

```
R[write to console]: Error: package or namespace load failed for 'grpreg' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
 unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.


R[write to console]: Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\willi\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_27800\977170058.py", line 1, in <module>
    base=importr('grpreg')

  File "C:\Users\willi\anaconda3\envs\fun_regression_3.7\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\packages.py", line 485, in importr
    return package.__rdata__

  File "C:\Users\willi\anaconda3\envs\fun_regression_3.7\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface_lib\conversion.py", line 45, in _

  File "C:\Users\willi\anaconda3\envs\fun_regression_3.7\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface.py", line 810, in __call__

RRuntimeError: Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.1.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
```

I would like to know how to fix the problem.

Comment: why run the R package? why not look for the python equivalent of the same? also if at all you must run the R PACKAGE, just write the Rscript and run it from python

Comment: The package is written in R only and there is no equivalent python package.

Comment: Technically speaking there are about two to three functions you would need. Functions that you might find in other python packages or write by yourself. Otherwise just run the code in R store the results and do whatver you want to the results in python